# C# populate datagridview and combobox inside of it

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I know how to populate datagridview, but I'm not sure how should I implement (at same time) the fill of a combobox according to the values of the first query.

```
query = "SELECT std.id, std.firstname, std.lastname, y.description
         FROM students AS std
         INNER JOIN years AS y ON y.id = std.id";
dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
dset = new DataSet();

dAdapter.Fill(dset, "students");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables["students"];
```

This works ok..but the data inside the datagridview is all Textbox. Although the `year` column should be a combobox, since there are two or more items.

```
    ID | Description
 ---------------------
     1 | First Grade
     2 | Second Grade
```

Thus said, I also would like the year to match the query.

```
ID | FirstName | LastName | Year (Combobox)
--------------------------------------------
 1     John       Lenon      Second Grade
 2     Maria      Keyl       Second Grade
 3     Stack      Overflow   First Grade
```

How can I accomplish this?

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, I'm getting somewhere.

```
string query = "SELECT std.id, std.std_name, std.std_last, y.id AS [yearID], y.description AS [yearDescription]" +
               "FROM students AS std " +
               "INNER JOIN years AS y ON y.id = std.year_id";
dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
dset = new DataSet();

dAdapter.Fill(dset, "students");
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables["students"];

var id = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    DataPropertyName = "id",
    HeaderText = "#",
    Name = "id",
};

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(id);

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn years = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

years.HeaderText = "Year";
years.DataSource = dset.Tables["students"];
years.DataPropertyName = "yearID";
years.ValueMember = "yearID";
years.DisplayMember = "yearDescription";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(years);
```

This works..the only problem I have now is that if I change the combobox index to another it doesn't change, it's kind of frozen. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value in `years.DataSource` should be different than the "students" table.

You're indicating where the `ComboBox` should get its available years from. For example, if you only wanted 1998 - 2000 in the drop-down, you could use something as simple as this:

```
years.DataSource = new List<int>{ 1998, 1999, 2000 };
```

If you wanted to quickly add all years between, say, 2000 - 2099, you could use this:

```
years.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(2000, 100);
```

Comment: You are correct. I've just added another datasource and its working.